# More clarification on an equivalence relation problem already answered

Tags: equivalence-relations

So this problem already has a solution: [Problem with Equivalence Relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51324/problem-with-equivalence-relations)

I'm good for the majority of it except for part c), I wasn't able to figure that out on my own or by looking at the explanation.

Perhaps I still don't fully comprehend what equivalence classes are, but from my understanding they are subsets of out general set A, but they are special because they contain a group of elements that share the same equivalence relation characteristics? I mean the question asks to describe the set of equivalence relations that contain my set S. So it is beyond the elements that would be from set S that confuse me. Why would any other sorts of elements be a part of the intersection of that group of equivalence relations if the one set they share is the set S?

Answer (score 0):

Before we get into this, recall the definition of [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) and [equivalence class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Equivalence_class).
An equivalence relation is just a way to compare two elements. If two elements are equivalent, they belong to the same equivalent class.

For c) What we are searching is a equivalence relation $\sim$ such that for all elements $\overset{\rightarrow}{x}\in S,\ \overset{\rightarrow}{x}=(x_1,x_2)$ we have $x_1\sim x_2$. This is meant by equivalence relations on the real line that 'contain' $S$. We need more elements, than the one in $S$ since the relation defined by $S$ i.e. $x\sim_s y \Leftrightarrow y=x+1, x\in ]0,2[ $ is NOT an *equivalence* relation.

Furthermore, we want $\sim$ to be the smallest equivalence relation containing $S$. With this in mind, you should be able to follow the ideas from your linked post and solve C.

Does this bring some clarity to what is asked?